# How to fix element p size

Tags: html, css

I'm working in one html/js apps similar to powerpoint, so the apps leave you create slider and show them in any type of screen (they are big screen but with not that many pixel, example one screen make 128x90 [px], the screen make 2x1 [metters])

At the creation process the people can choose different font sizes in px (11, 12, 14 .... 100), at this moment i add text and the parent element have this css

```
.text-show{
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 11px !important;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-weight: lighter !important;
    line-height: 1 !important;
}
```

And others css (i working in someone project and one old dev add to many parent and css).

My problem is that when i add text, for example

```
<p> some text <span style="font-size: 11px">other text</span></p>
```

At the creator part i get for the size of ‘p‘ this ‘SOMEx12px‘, but in the end result i get ‘SOMEx12.66px‘

And because i'm working with not to many pixel, the 0.66px variation is visible (i had other element, so is more the sum other this little diff that make the problem).

So my question is way and how i can fix this problem, i verify the css and i can not find any weird.

For test it, i use the same browser to create the slider and to see it, the screen have the same browser too.

Comment: Please add a working jsFiddle with your problem. It's hard to guess where that rule is coming from.

Answer (score -1):

You have try to use a Normalize.css file? the browser some time add part of code that you don't need, maybe something like `p{font-size:110%}` or `spam{font-size:110%}` Also could be that are inside your normalize part.

Comment: This is not a valid answer to the problem. Answers should provide an explanation to the problem and preferably a code example on how to fix the problem...

Comment: @Narxx If you don't don't understand it's your problem. I have write a explanation and propose a possible error. Place don't play just for have point.

Comment: I try to help, and follow StackOverflow's rules. My comment is here to contribute back to the community. I'm sorry you are offended by it, I did not have any intention of offending you personally.

Comment: @Narxx It's not about offense, I have answer to check the css file because could be the solution for him. This it'a an answer. Anyway if you want make the forum cop you can do... Peace!